# Display date according to the time zone of device

Tags: java, android, datetime

2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400
or 2010-06-14 02:21:49+0400

The above is the string coming from my webservice...
is there a way to convert this string to the date according to the local machine time zone

I used Simpledateformatter .. but not able to display correctly.. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for date formatting (from date string to date object). Pattern will be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`

Example:

```
String dateStr = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

**PS** To use TimeZone, you can use `TimeZone.getDefault()` and add it to SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
output -- Wed Mar 31 14:37:33... but i want 2010-03-31 02:37 PM

Comment: @xydev, that's not what you asked initially (`is there a way to convert this string to the date according to the local machine time zone`). Could you please update your question further so that we know exactly what you want?