# Getting device's local timezone

Tags: java, android, timezone

2010-06-14 02:21:49+0400 or 2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400

is there a way to convert this string to the date according to the local machine time zone with format 2010-06-14 02:21 AM

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display date according to the time zone of device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312220/display-date-according-to-the-time-zone-of-device)

Comment: I've just answered this question recently.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding to what @org.life.java and @Erica said, here's what you should do

```
String dateStr = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
String newDateStr = sdf.format(date);

System.out.println(newDateStr);
```

Then `newDateStr` will be your new date formatted string.

---

**UPDATE** @xydev, the example I gave you works, see the full source code below:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package testcases;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String dateStr = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
            sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
            String newDateStr = sdf.format(date);

            System.out.println(newDateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: `2010-06-14 08:21:49 AM`

Comment: i am getting this value for "Date date" Mon Jun 14 11:51:49 GMT+00:00 2010 .... and application crashes on reaching the step "
String newDateStr = sdf.format(date);
"

Comment: thanks.. i got it... error was caused by this code   //String dateStr = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
//   SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
//   TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
//   sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
//   date = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
//
//   try {
//    dates = sdf.parse(date);
//   } catch (ParseException e) {
//    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//    e.printStackTrace();
//   }

Answer (score 7):

Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String string1 = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date date = sdf.parse(string1);
```

Note: I am not sure the same class is available in andriod.

Comment: Good answer. You probably need to capitalise the "mm" for the month though, otherwise you'll be getting minutes there. :)

Comment: Android is based on Java 1.5 so the class exists.

Comment: There **must** is no space between `ss` and `Z` in your pattern.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman Of course it is an object of TimeZone, it holds default timezone, that can be retrieved by `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

You can do all sorts of fancy formatting and localisation of dates using the DateFormat class. There's very good, complete documentation at the start of the API page here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Most regular cases can be handled with the built in SimpleDateFormat object. Its details are here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

The SimpleDateFormat output pattern string for the example you have above would be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a
```

Comment: @The-Elite-Gentlemen, yes, that was the format of the output string which xydev requested; "2010-06-14 02:21 AM". :)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that if you are running on the emulator your timezone is always GMT. I just spent 2 hours in trying to understand why my application does not give me the right time (the one my computer displays) until I realized it is because of the emulator.

To check you are running on the emulator use

```
if (Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk")){
  // your code here for example if curtime has the emulator time 
  // since midnight in milliseconds then
  curtime += 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;   // to add 2 hours from GMT
}
```