# Joda time gives incorrect time for timezone

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime, wear-os

I am creating a spinner in Android, then obtaining the value of the spinner and trying to figure out the local time in the timezone ID.

In the following example timeZoneID is the string representation of the timezone ID e.g. "America/Chicago" etc.

```
            DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneID);
            DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneID));
            DateTime localTime1 = now.toDateTime(tz);

            float minuteRotation = localTime1.getMinuteOfDay() / 30f * (float) Math.PI;
            float hourRotation = ((localTime1.getHourOfDay() + localTime1.getMinuteOfDay() / 60f) / 6f) * (float) Math.PI;
```

The problem however, is that the local time of the time zone is always wrong. For instance if the PST time is supposed to be 8 PM, then I get back 5 PM from the code above.

All the timezone ID's are correct and are obtained from Joda time itself which were populated in the following spinner:

```
        Set<String> zoneIds = DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ");
        ArrayList<String> TZ1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String zoneId:zoneIds) {
            TZ1.add("("+dateTimeFormatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(zoneId)).print(0) +") "+zoneId+", "+TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId).getDisplayName());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < TZ1.size(); i++) {
            adapter.add(TZ1.get(i));
        }
        final Spinner TZone = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.TimeZoneEntry);
        TZone.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(int i = 0; i < TZ1.size(); i++) {
            if(TZ1.get(i).equals(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName())) {
                TZone.setSelection(i);
            }
        }
```

Question: why am I getting incorrect local time from Joda time? I am at my wits end trying to figure this issue out!

Comment: Is the local time of the device set to another time zone? This may cause the offset. You can check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312680/getting-devices-local-timezone

Comment: The local time is also set to PST - so technically selecting America/Los Angeles should also give the same time as the local time.

Comment: Have you verified with 100% certainty the value of `timeZoneID` is what you think it is? Why are you adding parentheses around the zone when loading it into the spinner?

Answer (score 0):

The following code as test reports the correct local time for my time zone settings:

```
@Test
public void timeTest()
{
    String timeZoneID = "Europe/Berlin";
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneID);
    DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZoneID));
    DateTime localTime1 = now.toDateTime(tz);
    System.err.println(localTime1 + " " + localTime1.getZone().getID() + " Default: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
}
```

Shouldn't be the current setting be `PDT` instead of `PST` currently? And "America/Chicago" is 3 hours off PDT.

Comment: Thats the exact same code as mine. That is really bizzare it works for you and not on my side.

Comment: My output is `2015-07-28T20:43:41.956+02:00 Europe/Berlin Default: Europe/Berlin`. Can you try on another device? I've no android device here to test.